# Map custom join table to model in database-first approach with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have the following model:

```
public class Employer {
    int EmployerId { get; set; }
    List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee {
    int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}

public class IrrelevantModel {
    int IrrelevantModelId { get; set; }
}
```

We have the following database structure:

```
TABLE Employer
 COLUMN EmployerId

TABLE Employee
 COLUMN EmployeeId

TABLE IrrelevantModel
 COLUMN IrrelevantModelId

TABLE Links
 COLUMN EmployerId
 COLUMN EmployeeId
 COLUMN IrrelevantId
```

We **don't** use a normal join table like this:

```
TABLE EmployerEmployees
 COLUMN EmployerId
 COLUMN EmployeeId
```

Is there a way to tell Entity Framework, using database first approach, that we are using a custom link table and how it is mapped? The goal here is to make the design decision on database level unknown to the model in code. So, when someone does `new Employer().Employees.Add(new Employee())`, that link between employer and employee is saved in the links table. In the current situation we have to make a Link object with properties for all possible joins, which is really pressing maintainability.

Note: The link table is made this way for performance gain en simplicity with traditional SQL queries used in views in our application.